# How to pass the events/values from alertdialog or popup window to an activity in Android MVP?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-mvp

I'm following the MVP pattern for my app and I am having confusion about adding the event listeners to the alert dialog and also passing the text view value from alert dialog to activity back. Which is the best approach?.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use of **Listener** is the best approach. How? Let see-

I am assuming you are using custom dialog, for this apply these steps to get proper callbacks-

1. Make an Interface inside your **CustomDialog** class which will return you the callback event.
2. Implement that interface in your **Presenter/ViewModel** class.
3. Now your **Presenter/ViewModel** Override that callback method and from here you can use that for your next task.
4. Pass **Presenter/ViewModel** reference to your Custom Dialog as the instance of Interface.
5. Now call the interface method where you want inside your Dialog.

> A Quick Code Example(in kotlin)

**CustomDialog**

```
    class CustomDialog : DialogFragment() {

    var listener: Listener? = null
    var messageText = ""

    override fun onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState: Bundle?): Dialog {
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(this.activity)
        val rootView = activity?.layoutInflater?.inflate(R.layout.dialog_custom, null)
        isCancelable = false
        val messageTextView: TextView? = rootView?.findViewById(R.id.messageTextView)
        val okButton: Button? = rootView?.findViewById(R.id.okButton)

        if (messageText.isNotBlank()) {
            messageTextView?.text = messageText
        }

        okButton?.setOnClickListener {
            listener?.customOkClicked()
            dismiss()
        }

        builder.setView(rootView)
        return builder.create()
    }

    override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
        dialog?.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE)
        dialog?.window?.setBackgroundDrawable(ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT))

        return super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState)
    }

    interface Listener {
        fun customOkClicked()
    }
}
```

**YouPresenter**

```
class MyPresenter: CustomDialog.Listener {

    .
    .
    // other code

    override fun customOkClicked() {
        // your next step
    }
 }
```

**YourActivity**

```
class YourActivity: Activity() {

  .
  .

  fun showCustomDialog() {
     CustomDialog().apply {
            this.listener = presenter  // reference of your presenter class. 
            this.messageText = msg
        }.show(supportFragmentManager, "custom_dialog_tag")
  }

}
```

**Note:** You can apply same approach with the **MVVM**, do the same thing with your **ViewModel** in case.

Hope this is the answer you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You should LayoutInflater to inflate your dialog into a view. Then you can easily retrive the value as follows :

```
LayoutInflater layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog, null, false);
EditText textView = view.findViewById(R.id.editText);
String text = textView.getText();
```